# Javascript can't run with dynamic views loaded from ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a problem when I try to load template into ui-view using ui-router. The javascript is loaded but not running on loaded views.
The full story is that:
I have a template in HTML with full js, css... files. Everything runs perfectly in HTML. Then I add AngularJS with UI-Router to make the page dynamic with view. 
My code looks like:

```
<head>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>This is the content of dynamic view</h1>
<div ui-view></div>

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jqueryui.min.js"></script>
... 
<script src="isotype.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

When I load the view from ui-router, the layout is correct. But no javascript effects are running.
How can I fix that? I want to load a list of js files in the index.html so that when it change the ui-view, i don't have to load them again.

Comment: jQuery should/MUST go before angular. Read about jquery inside of angular

Comment: I have moved them before angular, but in vain. I have also tried ocLazyLoad but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the way to fix this problem. The file custom.js which I config every elements in the html template, will be put in the HTML template file.
When the index file loads the HTML template, it will load the custom.js file also.