# js from base.html is not getting applied to angular/materializecss templates loaded in ui-view

Tags: angularjs, django-templates, materialize, django-staticfiles

I have the below structure where `protect.html` extends from `base.html` and angularjs loads angular templates in `ui-view` placed in `protect.html`. `base.html` contains all `js` and `css`.

Now my question is `js` from `base.html` is not getting applied to angular/materializecss templates loaded in `ui-view`.

I can see all files loaded in `developer tool`.

When I put these `js` files in each file to be loaded in `ui-view` everything works fine.

**The problem seem to be that, materialize js is not getting applied to html or it is loading before html elements are loaded**

When I add materialize js to loaded page everything works.

Any help/pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks.

**base.html**

```html
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

        {% block title %}
            <title>Raxak Protect</title>
        {% endblock title %}
        
        {% block basecss %}
            <link  href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection">
        {% endblock basecss %}
    
        {% block css %}
        {% endblock css %}

</head>
        {% block header %}
        {% endblock header %}

<body id="login-page">

 {% block navigation %}
     {% endblock navigation %}
     {% block content %}
     {% endblock content %}
     {% block footer %}
     {% endblock footer %}

</body>

    {% block basejs %}

        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "{% static 'js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src = "{% static 'jquery/jquery-ui.js' %}"></script>
        <script src = "{% static 'angular/angular.js' %}"></script>
        <script src = "{% static 'angular/angular-ui-router.js' %}"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "{% static 'js/materialize.js' %}"></script>
        
        <script src = "{% static 'angular/angular-materialize.js' %}"></script>
        <script src = "{% static 'angular/underscore.js'%}"></script>
        <script src = "{% static 'angular/angular-route.js' %}"></script>
        <script src = "{% static 'angular/restangular.js' %}"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "{% static 'js/perfect-scrollbar.min.js' %}"></script>
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.dataTables.js' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/dataTables.material.js' %}"></script>

        <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src = "{% static 'js/custom-script.js' %}"></script> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src = "{% static 'datejs/moment.js' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src = "{% static 'js/csrf.js' %}" ></script>
    {% endblock basejs %}

    {% block js %}
    {% endblock js %}
</html>
```

**protect.html**

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block title %}
<title>Raxak Protect</title>
{% endblock title %}

{% block css %} 
<link  href="{% static 'css/protect.css' %}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection">
{% endblock css %}

{% block header %}
{% include 'protect/header.html' %}
{% endblock header %}

{% block navigation %}
<div id="container" ng-app="raxak_protect" ng-init="auth.user={{ user.cpeUser.id }}; auth.username ='{{ user.username }}'">
    {% include 'protect/protect_navigation.html' %}
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}
    <div ui-view="">
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock navigation %}

{% block footer %}
{% include 'protect/footer.html' %}
{% endblock footer %}

{% block js %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/raxak_protect.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/controllers.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/b_controllers.js' %}"></script>

</script>
{% endblock js %}
```

Comment: This is similar questions [here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538175/javascript-cant-run-with-dynamic-views-loaded-from-ui-router), but not clean solutiion.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the materialize js is loaded before the html content.

Try adding the `<script>` tag that calls the materialize js to the last.

```html
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "{% static 'js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src = "{% static 'jquery/jquery-ui.js' %}"></script>
        <script src = "{% static 'angular/angular.js' %}"></script>
        <script src = "{% static 'angular/angular-ui-router.js' %}"></script>
         
        <script src = "{% static 'angular/underscore.js'%}"></script>
        <script src = "{% static 'angular/angular-route.js' %}"></script>
        <script src = "{% static 'angular/restangular.js' %}"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "{% static 'js/perfect-scrollbar.min.js' %}"></script>
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.dataTables.js' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/dataTables.material.js' %}"></script>

        <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src = "{% static 'js/custom-script.js' %}"></script> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src = "{% static 'datejs/moment.js' %}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src = "{% static 'js/csrf.js' %}" ></script>



<script type = "text/javascript" src = "{% static 'js/materialize.js' %}"></script>
        
        <script src = "{% static 'angular/angular-materialize.js' %}"></script>
```

**The above may solve your problem with a probability of 50%.**

**Else, try to call materialize js in a callback function after loading html contents.**
Difficult to provide an example without your JS code